# Converting String value to Datetime in SQL Server throws exception

Tags: sql-server

I'm struggling with converting nvarchar to date times.

I have current query:

```
SELECT  
    ACCT_NBR, BANK_CODE, ACCT_CODE, ACCT_CCY, HOLDER_CODE, 
    ACCT_GRP_CODE, RECEPTION_TIMES
FROM 
    VIEW_ID_MONITORING
WHERE 
    STATUS = 'EXPECTING' 
    AND ACCT_GRP_CODE = 'ID_ACME_SHIPPING_EUROPE' 
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), '2017-08-03T11:00:00+02:00', 127) = RECEPTION_START
```

I want to check if the `RECEPTION_START` is the same as today, 11'o clock with an offset of 2 hours.

But running this query throws following exception

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed
>   when converting date and/or time from character string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not converting string to datetime in your query. You are converting varchar to varchar.

Comment: What data type is RECEPTION_START ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you are converting a `varchar` to `varchar`, as Peter commented.
Second, this kind of value can't be converted to `DateTime`, but it can be converted to `DateTimeOffset`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, '2017-08-03T11:00:00+02:00', 127)
```

Returns `03.08.2017 11:00:00 +02:00`

Comment: it does convert to datetime2, which truncates the +2:00. That you for making that point though, I would have never checked otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

So your error condition is not a problem converting datetime to varchar, but rather converting varchar to datetime.

Is RECEPTION_START a datetime value? If it is, datetime has higher precedence than varchar, which means sql-server is actually trying to do the following.

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), '2017-08-03T11:00:00+02:00', 127)) = RECEPTION_START
```

Thats a problem because your input string is 25 long, and varchar(24) is cutting a zero off the end and because you can't conver something with time zone info to a datetime (only datetime2 or datetimeoffset)

### try instead following solution:

```
CONVERT(datetimeoffset,'2017-08-03T11:00:00+02:00') = RECEPTION_START
```

Also you'll need to check if RECEPTION_START is datetime, datetime2 or datetimeoffset. Unless it's datetimeoffset, you're comparing something with a timezone set with a value that doesn't. Make sure that's what you want. if you convert '2017-08-03T11:00:00+02:00' to datetime2, the +2:00 gets truncated.

To confirm that it's not a problem converting from your date string to varchar.

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), '2017-08-03T11:00:00+02:00', 127)
```

which works for me on both 2012 and 2014. Only issue with it is that you're setting varchar 24 type when the input string is actually 25 long. but that shouldn't matter if you use solution avbove.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use
`'2017-08-03T11:00:00+02:00Z'` because mode `127` expects this format:

`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmmZ`

or use `126` instead of `127` because this expects:

`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm`